# mysql_query ORDER BY the average of elements divided to each other in 1 line

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a database of workers.
They have joined in different data and their speed of work is vary.
Work is creating boxes.

So I need to have the table ordered by average boxes per day.

```
    $rListQ = mysql_query("SELECT joinDate,box FROM table ORDER BY (box/(time()- joinDate)/86400) DESC");
    while ($rListF = mysql_fetch_array($rListQ)) {
       echo ...
    }
```

This of course doesn't work.
How can you help me about the ORDER BY?

Comment: Calculate your sorting field in a subquery and wrap it into another query, which would then order on that field.

Comment: Tables adn some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
SELECT 
    joinDate,box,(box/((NOW()- joinDate)/86400)) as avgt
FROM 
    table1 
ORDER BY avgt DESC;
```

Or

```
SELECT 
    joinDate,SUM(box),(SUM(box)/((NOW()- joinDate)/86400)) as avgt
FROM 
    table1 
GROUP BY
    joinDate
ORDER BY avgt DESC;
```